# Acessing phone address book using J2ME and sending message using mobilephone SIM card

Tags: java-me

Can one access a mobile phone address book via J2me? And if yes, how then can I send a message from a custom application through the SIM card?

Answer (score 2):

To access phone address book, look up JSR 75 and JSR 120. There are detailed examples [here](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/ttips/pim/) and [here](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/wma/)